# Is there a way to add ajax hooks without editing the functions.php file?

Tags: ajax

I am using the plugin code snippets and I'm quite liking it. Except for the fact that when I want to register an ajax hook it will try to register after all the hooks are registered by WordPress. I just hate the idea of working directly in the functions.php file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean like [writing a plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/)?

Comment: Well isn't that a bit overkill? Writing a whole plugin for just 1 ajax call?

Comment: Why not? Plugins are just PHP files with a comment at the top, putting it in a plugin is just as heavy on the server as putting it in `functions.php`. There's nothing fundamentally costly about the number of plugins on a server, or plugins themselves. It's all about what the code does, and that cost happens wether it's in `functions.php` or a plugin file regardless

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use the old legacy AJAX API? you could just make AJAX requests to the REST API instead? It's actually easier to debug, and gives you a lot more options

Comment: Well I am kinda on a time limit, it has to be done today and I have never done it before. So I gues it's just the functions.php then. How would I make a request to the Rest Api then and what is the difference?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/